# insert an element in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have now known why the linked list was not updated from the previous questions. It turns out that I have to iterate the coordinates of x but that's not important in this question of mine.

When I insert an element in the linked list the elements before where I want to insert a value disappears. For example I have elements that would print out "helo" and I want to insert another 'l' after e, the output would be "(space)ello. Here is my insertion code and structure:

```
struct node {
struct node *previous;
int c;
int x;
int y;
struct node *next;
}*head;

void checker(int ch, int xpos, int ypos)
{
    int flag=0;
    struct node *temp,*temp1,*var,*insert_node;
    var=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    insert_node=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp->x==xpos && temp->y==ypos)
        {
            insert_node->c=ch;
            insert_node->x=xpos;
            insert_node->y=ypos;
            insert_node->next=NULL;
            temp1=temp;
                while(temp1!=NULL)
                {
                    if(temp1->y==ypos)
                    temp1->x++;
                    temp1=temp1->next;
                }
                var->next=insert_node;
                insert_node->next=temp;
                head=var;

            flag=1;
            break;
        }
            var=temp;
            temp=temp->next;
    }
    if(flag==0)
        characters(ch,xpos,ypos);
}
```

It seems like var has only one element inside instead of two, it takes "h" from helo forgranted.

Comment: You shouldn't do a malloc on temp or var.  You overwrite the malloc on temp when you assign head to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You throw away the list from the original head up to the point you find the matching x and y in the list when you assign `head = var`. Sit down and draw a couple of pictures to convince yourself that is wrong.

To insert a new node before the matching node in the list: keep track of the current node in the list and the previous node visited. Then when you are ready to insert a new node in front of current_node, do this:

```
insert_node->next = current_node;
if (previous_node == NULL)
    head = insert_node;
else
    previous_node->next = insert_node;
```

In your code, `temp` plays the role of `current_node` (the one you are examining). You don't have a pointer to the previous node, so declare one. Set current_node to head, previous_node to NULL, then start running the list, and when you find the node in the list you want to put `insert_node` in front of, use the code above. Note the special case when you want to insert at the front of the list. I leave it as an exercise to figure out what to do if you want to insert the new node after `current_node`.

Comment: This works fine Sir, however I am still confused why it works. I am doing self study on this so I might have missed a few points. I would like to ask if even if I only have a pointer to the last previous node, would I still have the values of all previous node? Like as what I understand here, previous_node points to the last element before I want to insert a node. So if I print previous node, I would have all the values before the point where I want to insert a node? (Sorry if I am making you confused) Thank you.

Comment: Pointers can be very confusing, but keep at it and you'll have that "aha!" moment. To your question, the list itself contains pointers to all nodes in the list except the head. The head pointer remedies that. When working on the list, it is helpful to point to the node you are working on (current_node) and the node immediately before the current_node (previous_node). Current_node points to one node, previous_node to what was current_node the last time around the loop (and NULL during the first iteration), so you only have the values of at most two nodes with those pointers.

Comment: If insert_node is placed before current_node in the list, insert_node->next must be set to point to current_node. Insert_node is still not in the list, because no part of the list points to insert_node. To make insert_node part of the list, previous_node->next must be changed from current_node to insert_node (except when head points to current_node, then head must be changed to insert_node). Rewrite the loop to instead place insert_node *after* current_node in the list, and you'll learn something about pointers.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var->next=insert_node;
        insert_node->next=temp;
```

should be:

```
        insert_node->next=temp->next;
        temp->next=insert_node;
```